# update table column from a second database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've followed examples from other posting to achieve this but am getting the following error:

> The objects "otherDB.dbo.someTable" and "someDB.dbo.someTable" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Here's the SQL Statement

```
UPDATE [someDB].[dbo].[someTable]
SET [someDB].[dbo].[someTable].[Name] = [otherDB].[dbo].[someTable].[Name]
FROM [someDB].[dbo].[someTable]
INNER JOIN [otherDB].[dbo].[someTable]
   ON [someDB].[dbo].[someTable].[ID] = [otherDB].[dbo].[someTable].[ID]
```

As you can see, I simple want to update the `[Name]` in `[someBD].[someTable]` from `[otherDB].[someTable]`

From what I can see in other similar queries, this should work but I wonder if I need to do something different because it's coming from a different database?

Any pointers/help much appreciated.

Comment: If this database is on the same server instance, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using an alias?

```
UPDATE db1
SET db1.[Name] = db2.[Name]
FROM [someDB].[dbo].[someTable] db1
INNER JOIN [otherDB].[dbo].[someTable] db2
   ON db1.[ID] = db2.[ID]
```

Comment: using db as alias for a table is a bit misleading, but the syntax is correct, +1, and now you got more points than i got the whole day.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I agree but I chose it to show the distinction between the databases.

Comment: Oh and if I could +2 for the quick response I would :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using aliases:

```
UPDATE
[someDB].[dbo].[someTable]
SET
s.[someDB].[dbo].[someTable].[Name] = o.[otherDB].[dbo].[someTable].[Name]
FROM
[someDB].[dbo].[someTable] s
INNER JOIN
[otherDB].[dbo].[someTable] o
ON
s.[someDB].[dbo].[someTable].[ID] = o.[otherDB].[dbo].[someTable].[ID]
```

Comment: Humm what's the problem with my aliases?